# enzyme jest find by displayName not working?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have this very simple stateless component

```
const Text = () => 'text'
Text.displayName = 'MyText'
export default Text
```

My test case

```
import Text from './Components/Text'

import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

it('render Text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Text />)
    expect(wrapper.find('Text').length).toBe(1)
})
```

What's wrong? I also tried `exists()`, seems like this is not working `wrapper.find('Text')`

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `<Text />` so `wrapper` will contain result of `Text`'s rendering without that tag itself.

If you check `wrapper.debug()` you will see just `"text"`.

Comment: so how should I test it?

Comment: expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1)

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac is there a point to test it like so? what if that component is a container, how to test whether it exist on the page?

Comment: @Hoknimo If it contains another component, then you could check if the wrapped component exist by the same principle, specifying the component name. `expect(wrapper.find('WrappedComponent').length).toEqual(1)  // exists()`

Comment: it doesn't have other component

Comment: `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()` will be enough since there are no actions expected